# Using pkg to convert a console app to an .exe is it safe?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an application in nodejs and I want to send it to other people but I don't want those people to see my code and steal it for example, when converting it into an .exe app with PKG, can people continue to see the source code? what would be the best way to make my application secure? It is a console app made 100% in nodejs